# Count number of list items then add style based on quantity

Tags: jquery

I want to be able to count the number of list items within a UL and then set the padding on them based on the number of li's there are.

To count the number of li's I think I need to do:

```
var count = $("ul.nav li").length
```

But can I then use some IF logic to say something like:

```
if count==10 then 'ul.nav li "style=padding:0 0 0 40px"'
if count==9 then 'ul.nav li "style=padding:0 0 0 50px"'
if count==8 then 'ul.nav li "style=padding:0 0 0 60px"'
etc...
```

I've tried this, but it doesn't seem to work. Any ideas?

Comment: Sure you can. Give it a shot. Your syntax is obviously incorrect, but your logic is fine.

Comment: Use the length as a class name, and do the layout inside CSS. Keep CSS out of your JavaScript code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that in a convenient way using CSS classes combined with the logic you provided.

First write a CSS class for each length you want:

```
.li-count-4
{
    padding: 0 0 0 40px;
    /*any other styles you want*/
}

.li-count-3
{
    padding: 0 0 0 30px;
    /*any other styles you want*/
}
```

Then you write the javascript part

```
var lis = $("ul.nav li");
var count = $("ul.nav li").length;

switch (count)
{
    case 4:
        lis.addClass('.li-count-4');
        break;
    case 3:
        lis.addClass('.li-count-3');
        break;
    //other cases
}
```

Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

If I really discovered the sequence...

```
$("ul.nav li").css( "padding", "0 0 0 "+(14-count)*10+"px" );
```

Answer (score 0):

The right way to do it using jQuery would be:

```js
if (count == 10)
  pad = 40;
else if(count == 9)
  pad = 50;

// The rest .....
// and finally
$('ul.nav li').css('padding', '0 0 0'+ pad + 'px');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var elem = $("ul.nav li")
, styles = {
    7: 60,
    8: 50,
    9: 40
};
elem.each(function(i) {
    if (styles[i] !== undefined) {
      elem.css("padding", "0 0 0 " + styles[i] + "px")
    }
});
```

```js
var elem = $("ul.nav li")
, styles = {
    7: 60,
    8: 50,
    9: 40
};
elem.each(function(i) {
    if (styles[i] !== undefined) {
      elem.css("padding", "0 0 0 " + styles[i] + "px")
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav">
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
    <li>6</li>
    <li>7</li>
    <li>8</li>
    <li>9</li>
    <li>10</li>
</ul>
```